# Length of a regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

What is the definition for the length of a regular expression? This question might sound simple, yet I cannot find a definition. Do I only count letters from the alphabet? Do * and $\cup$ count?
For example: let r = $(ab)^*\cup$ $a$. What is $|r|$?

Answer (score 7):

I assume, you want to define the length of a regular expression such that you can make statements like: *The Thompson construction creates an NFA from a regular expression with a number of states that is linear in the length of the expression.*

In that case, it is crucial to include operator symbols, otherwise the above statement would not be true for the expression $a^{\ast\ast\ast\ast\ast\cdots\ast}$.

However, if you preprocess expressions such that there are no nested Kleene stars or trailing $\varepsilon$s, then it does not matter much, as then the different definitions only differ by a constant factor. A short write up on this which I think is quite good, you can find in [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eshallit/Papers/re3.pdf).¹

¹ Keith Ellul, Bryan Krawetz, Jeffrey Shallit, and Ming-wei Wang. *Regular Expressions: New Results and Open Problems.* Journal of Automata, Languages and Combinatorics, 10(4) 2005

Answer (score 7):

There are two conventions I know of.

One is defining the size of a regular expression as the size of the binary tree representing the expression. As such, the size of the expression is the total number of symbols in the expression, counting $\emptyset$, $a\in \Sigma$, $*$, $|$ and $\cdot$ (parentheses are not counted).

An other definition removes the $\cdot$ (concatenation product) from being counted. This is somewhat usefull in the [Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction): the constructed NFA for $e$ has at most $2|e|$ states (this is due to the fact that the concatenation symbol does not increase the size of the automaton).